# Convert Gulp-TSLint to Gulp-ESLint

Tags: typescript, gulp, eslint, tslint, typescript-eslint

I have a Gulp task that needs updating from `gulp-tslint` to `gulp-eslint` as outlined below

```
const { src } = require('gulp');
const config = require('./config');

const plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
const plumber = require('./plumber-wrapper');
const mergeStream = require('merge-stream');
const gulpTsLint = require('gulp-tslint');
const tslint = require('tslint');

function lintTask () {

    const { srcDir, jsDir, sassFiles } = config
    const tsLintProgram = tslint.Linter.createProgram('./tsconfig.json')
    const typeScript = src(`${srcDir}${jsDir}**/*.ts`)

        .pipe(plumber())
        // lint according to rules defined in `tslint.json`
        .pipe(
            gulpTsLint({
                formatter: 'verbose',
                /**
                 * type-checked rules require a TypeScript `program` object.
                 * ensure 'Linter.createProgram' is called inside the gulp task else the
                 * contents of the files will be cached if this tasks is called again,
                 * e.g. as part of a `watch` task
                 */
                program: tsLintProgram
            })
        )
        .pipe(gulpTsLint.report());

    const sass = src(`${srcDir}${sassFiles().all}`)
        .pipe(plumber())
        // lint according to rules defined in `.stylelintrc`
        .pipe(
            plugins.stylelint({
                failAfterError: true,
                reporters: [
                    {
                        formatter: 'string',
                        console: true
                    }
                ],
                debug: true
            })
        );

    return mergeStream([typeScript, sass]);

};

module.exports = lintTask;
```

I have already migrated my NPM Tasks away from TSLint to ESLint, but I need to convert this last one and I'm struggling with a straight answer :( I would stipulate that this needs to be exported as lintTask at the end, for reasons :/

I have tried Google TBH, any tutorials I do find are JS related, not TS :(

Would someone be able to help?

Comment: _"any tutorials I do find are JS related, not TS"_ - does that matter? What you've shown is a JS file anyway, and what you apply ESLint to is just a matter of configuration. Where exactly are you stuck - can you lint your files _outside_ of the Gulp pipeline?

Comment: Yes I can, with an NPM task, but this gulp task is related to another part of the process... Ideally I'd like to keep this as intact as possible and just swap out the TSLint parts for ESLint... My understanding of gulp is limited :(

I'd like to make sure I add the correct plugins/rules etc...

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured it out, for those starting out in GULP, I did this and my TS files seem to lint again...

```
const { src } = require('gulp');
const config = require('./config');

const plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
const plumber = require('./plumber-wrapper');
const mergeStream = require('merge-stream');
const eslint = require('gulp-eslint');

function lintTask () {

    const { srcDir, jsDir, sassFiles } = config
    const typeScript = src(`${srcDir}${jsDir}**/*.ts`)
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());

    const sass = src(`${srcDir}${sassFiles().all}`)
        .pipe(plumber())
        // lint according to rules defined in `.stylelintrc`
        .pipe(
            plugins.stylelint({
                failAfterError: true,
                reporters: [
                    {
                        formatter: 'string',
                        console: true
                    }
                ],
                debug: true
            })
        );
    return mergeStream([typeScript, sass]);
};

module.exports = lintTask;
```